# Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0). Mysql vs Java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

While running the following query in mysql it's working perfectly fine.

```
SELECT
     a.feed_date, a.partner_name,
     SUM(a.count) as InputCount,
     SUM(CASE when (b.count is null) then 0 else b.count end) as OutputCount
FROM
 (SELECT year,week,partner_name, feed_date, count
  FROM op_dev.op_stats
  WHERE partner_name IN ('xyz, INC.','abc')
     AND mkt_elig_cd='Y'
     AND rel_grp_type_no='00000'
     AND feed_type='SellerChar') AS A
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT year,week,feed_date, partner_name, count
   FROM opt_dev.op_stats
   WHERE partner_name IN ('xyz, INC.','abc')
     AND mkt_elig_cd='Y'
     AND rel_grp_type_no='00000'
     AND feed_type='MSF') AS B
 ON A.partner_name = B.partner_name
   AND A.year=B.year
   AND A.week=B.week
GROUP BY A.week,A.year;
```

However, when I use the same query string and call it through Java code it is giving me the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

Can someone please help me to point out what's causing this issue.

Comment: Well, that SQL is impossible to read. Please reformat. --- How is SQL executed? The error is probably related to that, so you need to show it.

Comment: Thanks for the format Nguyen. I am using the sql through prepared statement passing the above string as a query.

Comment: Please include the Java code you use to execute this, and the entire stacktrace, not just the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you try to execute the query and specify parameter (check java and hibernate) but the query does not have parameters.

Comment: Yes,that was the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY clause must contain columns selected. If no column's selected, GROUP BY clause can use any column.
You can try this:

```
SELECT partner_name, feed_date,
     SUM(CASE WHEN feed_type='SellerChar' THEN count ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY year,week,feed_type) AS InputCount,
     SUM(CASE WHEN feed_type='MSF' THEN count ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY year,week,feed_type) AS OutputCount
FROM op_dev.op_stats
WHERE partner_name IN ('xyz, INC.','abc')
     AND mkt_elig_cd='Y'
     AND rel_grp_type_no='00000'
     AND (feed_type='SellerChar' OR feed_type='MSF')
```

Comment: I have removed the group by and still showing the same issue.